# Hexadecimal to Binary Conversion in Python

Tags: python, function, binary, hex

I am trying to prompt a Hexadecimal string which I need to convert to a Binary by calling another function. How can I do it python?

Suppose, my Input is ABAB. Then, there will be a function which will take this hexadecimal string and return the resulting binary values (1010101110101011).

Comment: Is there any particular length of this string? Could it be a hundred million digits?

Answer (score 3):

```
a = input()
hex_ = int(a, 16)
print(bin(hex_)[2:])
```

output:

```
ABAB
1010101110101011
```

I believe this is what you want